# Autofocus image blurry with iPhone X's telephoto or dual camera

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

Not sure if anyone experienced the same. When I used .builtInTelephotoCamera or .builtInDualCamera as my capture device, auto focus failed, the image was blurry. It was blurry whether I used `.autoFocus` or `.continuousAutoFocus`. The phone basically tried hard to focus, achieved kind of a focused state, then the image got blurred again.

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTelephotoCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
```

or

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
```

Wide-angle camera on the other hand worked fine.

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
```

I am using iPhone X and iOS 11.2 and Xcode 9.2 beta. The iPhone X hardware seems fine since focus is fine when using the phone's built-in Camera app with 1x and 2x photo modes. If this is a software issue, I suspect any iPhone (iPhone 7+, iPhone 8+, iPhone X) with dual camera will have same issue. Help..

Comment: Were you able to figure out any solutions I am noticing that this primarily occurs when the camera is close to an object.